# How can I ignore scrolling when clicking an anchor link but listen to scrolling otherwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently we have implemented a custom scrollspy because we couldn't get Bootstraps scrollspy to work properly.
The scrollspy:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            /*offsets = hashes.forEach(function (hash) {
             return $(hash).offset().top;
             }),*/
            last;
        if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
            if (scroll >= 20) {
                $(".arrow").addClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $(".arrow").removeClass("hidden");
            }
            hashes.forEach(function (hash) {
                if (hash === "#contact") {
                    if ($(hash).offset().top - navheight - 10 < scroll + 200) {
                        last = hash;
                    }
                } else if ($(hash).offset().top - navheight - 10 < scroll) {
                    last = hash;
                }
            });

            hashes.forEach(function (hash) {
                if (scroll >= ($(".notfooter").outerHeight() - 60 - $("#contact").outerHeight() - ($("#partners").outerHeight() / 2))) {
                    $('li:has(a[href="#contact"])').addClass("testing");
                    $('li:has(a[href="#partners"])').removeClass("testing");
                } else {
                    if (hash !== last) {
                        //console.log(hash + " not last hash");
                        $('li:has(a[href="' + hash + '"])').removeClass("testing");
                    } else if (hash === last) {
                        $('li:has(a[href="' + hash + '"])').addClass("testing");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The hashes array is simply an array with all our anchor links in it.

Then we have a class called `scrollto` to which we bind a click-event which then scrolls the window to the corresponding div.

```
$(".scrollto").on('click', function (event) {
        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
            $.get("/indexcontent", function (data) {
                    $("#bodycontent").html(data);
                    history.pushState(null, null, "/");
                    $('body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - navheight
                    }, 800, function () {
                        history.pushState(null, null, "");
                    });
                }
            );
        } else {
            $('body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - navheight
            }, 800, function () {
                history.pushState(null, null, "");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When a link is clicked it will first be marked as active (the class called `testing`) and we will start scrolling to that div. This is where the problem arises because as soon as we start scrolling the `$(window).scroll()` event triggers and will proceed to remove `testing` from the link we clicked and proceed to add and remove it from the links as we pass through them scrolling down the page.

What I thought I could do was to unbind the scroll event at the start of the `scrollto` click event and then rebind it when the scrolling is done, but even if I did this in the callback of the `animate()` it would still say that it was done and bind it before the scrolling was actually done.

So how should I think when trying to implement this? Is my reasoning about the bind/undbind trick in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to .on and .off the scroll event handler. You could .off it at the start of click handler and .on it, after the click handler scroll animation has ended, using a promise or a callback.

Yes I mean bind (jQuery .on()) and unbind (jQuery .off()).

Comment: Isn't that the same as .unbinding and .binding?